# Threading blocking GUI

Tags: thread-safety, wxpython, queue

I have a 2-way panel parsing a ListCtrl.  I still have my GUI blocked from this thread:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):    
    def __init__(self, DirQ, new_dbfQ, RemoveQ):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.DirQ = DirQ
        self.new_dbfQ = new_dbfQ
        self.RemoveQ = RemoveQ

    def run(self):
        """ worker """
        self.OpenDir = self.DirQ.get()
        self.new_dbf = self.new_dbfQ.get()
        self.RegRemove = self.RemoveQ.get()

        with open(str(self.OpenDir), 'r') as infile: 
            reader = csv.reader(infile)
            data = StringIO()

            writer = csv.writer(data)
            for line in csv.reader(self.new_dbf.splitlines()):
                row = line
                row_edit = re.sub(self.RegRemove,'', row[1])
                writer.writerow([row[0], row_edit])
                msg = data.getvalue()
                wx.CallAfter(Publisher().sendMessage, "update", msg)
```

I have a button the toggles:

```
def checkBtnClick3(self, event):        
    self.DirQ.put(self.OpenDir.GetValue())
    self.new_dbfQ.put(self.new_dbf)
    self.RemoveQ.put(self.RegRemove.GetValue())                
    t = MyThread(self.DirQ, self.new_dbfQ, self.RemoveQ)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
```

Do I need to add some kind of idle function on my frame class to free-up the GUI?

Comment: Try putting the setDaemon and start calls in the thread class's init

Comment: I set the start at the thread class, however I'm unable to set the setDaemon.  Do you have an example?

Comment: I would think self.setDaemon(True) would work...

Comment: I have both in that class, no change.  Perhaps a wxPostEvent instead of CallAfter?

Comment: I also notice my GUI is free if I comment-out the lines on the function the recieves the message.  Just let it pass through it.

Comment: Weird. I'm not seeing it. I would recommend asking on the wxPython Google group...